# How to append (collect) multi results from REST server in one fdMemTable

Tags: rest, delphi

There is REST server with methods to get transactions. From REST server I get results in fdMemTable page by page.

First I send request to understand number of pages (method GetTransactionsTotalPages), then in while loop I get resultsets several times from server (method GetTransactions).

I use components generated in REST debugger:

rcGetTransactions is REST client

reqGetTransactions is REST request.

rrdsaGetTransactions is REST response dataset adapter

fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages and fdmtGetTransactions are fdMemTable component.

After several executing of REST-request I get only last result package in fdMemTable.  How can I add new result package in fdMemTable to old result?

I tried

```
fdmtGetTransactions.FetchAgain;                                
fdmtGetTransactions.FetchAll;
```

as described here [Fetching and populating questions (FireDac)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Fetching_and_Populating_Questions_(FireDAC))

and

```
fdmtGetTransactions.BeginBatch;
fdmtGetTransactions.Append;                                     
fdmtGetTransactions.EndBatch;
```

but without result.

```
    procedure TfWarehouseTransactions.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     var TotalPages, Pagenumber: Integer;
     begin
          rcGetTransactions.BaseURL:= 'https://.../api';
          rreqGetTransactions.Resource:= 'warehouses/gettransactions';
          rreqGetTransactions.Method:=TRestRequestMethod.rmGET;
        
        
         //method to understand Total number of pages
         fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages.Active:=False;
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params.Clear;
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params.Add;
         reqGetTotalPagesTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].ContentType:= ctNone;
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Name:= 'token';
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Options:= [poDoNotEncode];
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Value:= TOKEN;
        
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params.Add;
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params[1].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST;
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params[1].ContentType:= ctNone;
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params[1].Name:= 'WarehouseId';
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params[1].Options:= [];
         reqGetTransactionControl.Params[1].Value:= ...;
        
         reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Execute;                                     
         TotalPages:= fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages.AsInteger;    
        
         
        fdmtGetTransactions.Active:=False;
        PageNumber:=1;
        fdmtGetTransactions.BeginBatch; 
        While PageNumber<=TotalPages do begin
         reqGetTransactions.Params.Clear;
         reqGetTransactions.Params.Add;
         reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
         reqGetTransactions.Params[0].ContentType:= ctNone;
         reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Name:= 'token';
         reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Options:= [poDoNotEncode];
         reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Value:= TOKEN;
        
          //other parameters
         
         reqGetTransactions.Params.Add;
         reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST;
         reqGetTransactions.Params[8].ContentType:= ctNone;
         reqTransactions.Params[8].Name:= 'PageNumber';
         reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Options:= [];
         reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Value:= IntToStr(PageNumber);
        
         reqGetTransactions.Execute;                                  
        
         PageNumber:= PageNumber+1;
       end;  //while
      fdmtGetTransaction.EndBatch;    
end;
```

**Solution:**
Finally I Use 3 fdMemTable components-

1. first for getting number of pages- fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages.
2. for getting results page by page- fdmtGetTransactions.
3. for appending (collecting) all the data- mtGetTransactions.

   ```
    procedure TfWarehouseTransactions.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
     var TotalPages, Pagenumber: Integer;
     begin
     rcGetTransactions.BaseURL:= 'https://.../api';
     rreqGetTransactions.Resource:= 'warehouses/gettransactions';
     rreqGetTransactions.Method:=TRestRequestMethod.rmGET;

     //to get Total number of pages
     fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages.Active:=False;
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params.Clear;
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params.Add;
     reqGetTotalPagesTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].ContentType:= ctNone;
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Name:= 'token';
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Options:= [poDoNotEncode];
     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Params[0].Value:= TOKEN;
     //and other parameters...       

     reqGetTransactionsTotalPages.Execute;                                     
     TotalPages:= fdmtGetTransactionsTotalPages.AsInteger;    

     fdmtGetTransactions.Active:=False;
     PageNumber:=1;

     //get results in the second fdMemTable (fdmtGetTransaction )
    While PageNumber<=TotalPages do begin
      reqGetTransactions.Params.Clear;
      reqGetTransactions.Params.Add;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[0].ContentType:= ctNone;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Name:= 'token';
      reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Options:= [poDoNotEncode];
      reqGetTransactions.Params[0].Value:= TOKEN;

      //other parameters...

      reqGetTransactions.Params.Add;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Kind:= TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[8].ContentType:= ctNone;
      reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Name:= 'PageNumber';
      reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Options:= [];
      reqGetTransactions.Params[8].Value:= IntToStr(PageNumber);

      reqGetTransactions.Execute;  

      mtGetTransaction.CopyDataSet(fdmtGetTransactions, [coAppend]);

      PageNumber:= PageNumber+1;
     end;  //while

     //third fdMemTable 
     mtGetTransaction..Active:= True;
   ```

   end;